# I have an application for webview but when I click links it automatically jump to default browser. I want to open the link in app itself but how?

Tags: java, android

I have an application for webview but when I click links it automatically jump to default browser. I want to open that link within the app itself but how?

Please someone help me for this? thank you...

Answer (score 0):

after loadUrl, write the below lines.

```
WebSettings webSettings = webView.getSettings();
webSettings.setJavaScriptEnabled(true);

webView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient()); //this line keep your website in the app.
```

Comment: it works but when a link outside the site like link for drive, it still jumping on the browser